# Generics type as a parameter

Tags: java, android, generics

The following code is the one I was using for updating some field's value in the database

```
public void updatesomeField(String registrationID) {
    ContentValues objValues;

    try {
        objDatabase=this.getWritableDatabase();
        objValues = new ContentValues();


        objValues.put(COLUMN_REGISTRATION_ID,registrationID);
        objDatabase.update(CUSTOMER_USERS_TABLE_NAME, objValues,null,null);
        objDatabase.close();
    } catch(Exception errorException) {
        Log.d("error",""+ errorException);
    }
}
```

---

Then I decided to use a generic approach and hence written the above code like

```
public <T> void update(String tableName, String columnName, T value) {
    ContentValues objValues;

    try {
        objDatabase=this.getWritableDatabase();
        objValues = new ContentValues();

        objValues.put(columnName,value);  ///here comes the error BECAUSE THE 'value'
        objDatabase.update(tableName, objValues,null,null);
        objDatabase.close();
    } catch(Exception errorException) {
        Log.d("error",""+ errorException);
    }
}
```

---

Error is because `ContentValues` is `final` and I cannot extend it to create my new own class to store my generic variable type. What optimization should be performed so that I can get rid of the error by having the same code?

---

### ANOTHER VERSION OF THE SAME QUESTION (IF THE ABOVE ASKED THING IS DIFFICULT TO UNDERSTAND)

I have a final predefined class `ContentValues` having method put which take parameters in the form of key and values.

---

[image]

---

However I want to implement a generic functionality and want to decide it on run time that what should be the type of the value

Comment: Have you tried to send value as `Object`? In Java every instance of a class extends Object. I think it can be put in `ContentValues`.

Comment: Not sure, but try `objValues.put(columnName,(String)value);` or `objValues.put(columnName,String.valueOf(value));`

Comment: and in case if type `Object` doesn't work then you may simply insert values by identifying which literal type the generic belongs to. for example: int, string, char, boolean, long, double, etc.

Comment: @MysticMagic I guess this will not help me as the value I want to store in the database may be of integer type,and also by doing so the code will loose the functionality for the purpose because of which i have implemented the generics

Comment: @waqaslam and how can i do this?

Comment: You can just use `instanceof`. I think that @waqaslam was referring to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write an [Adapter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) which does the dispatching for you:

```
class ContentValuesAdapter {

    private ContentValues values;

    public ContentValuesAdapter(ContentValues values) {
        this.values = values;
    }

    public void put(String columnName, Object value) {
        if(value instanceof String) {
            values.put(columnName, (String) value);
        } else if ( ... ) {
            ...
        }
    }

    public ContentValues getContentValues() {
        return this.values;
    }

    /* Delegate all other methods to the ContentValue instance. */
}
```

Now you can use this class instead of the original class, and keep your using code clean.

Comment: Nice answer,but what if I am looking for generics only?

Comment: This is about the only way you can use generics in combination with `ContentValues`.

Answer (score 1):

I use generic types throughout my applications, and have to say that one of the simplest (possibly not the best, or most efficient) ways of determining object type is `instanceof` - For e.g:

```
if(obj instanceof SiteContact){
    buildContactDropdownList((SiteContact)obj);
}else if(obj instanceof Delivery){
    buildDeliveryList((Delivery)obj);
}
```

You could quite easily wrap this up inside a helper class too.

Comment: why not the best and efficient?

Comment: I don't know if this is the preferred way or not. It's just what I use. That was more of a disclaimer for anyone downvoting :)

Answer (score 0):

If the `ContentValues` class belong to a third-party library and you have no access to its source code, then I'm afraid you're stuck with it.

Apparently, `ContentValues` contains a `put(String,String)` method. What you could do, is call the `toString()` method of `value`:

```
objValues.put(columnName, value.toString());
```

Since the `toString()` method is defined already in the class `Object`, you don't need to use generics for this. So you can just call your method:

```
public void update(String tableName, String columnName, Object value)
{
    ...
}
```